# How to create policy for wso2 identity server Entitlement

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have using Wso2 indendity server 5.7.

i have seen some document for wso2.
link:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Entitlement+with+APIs#EntitlementwithAPIs-addPolicy()

my problem how to use this things in postman.

i have seen some document in rest api but in rest api documentation create policy rest api not available.

Rest Api Document:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Entitlement+with+REST+APIs

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation you pointed was the SOAP APIs. There is no rest API for creating XACML policy in WSO2 IS. If your requirement is to use postman to publish the policies, you can refer to [this](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/making_soap_requests/). It explains how to send the SOAP request from postman

Comment: do u know how to use soap api? bcz i have not find out endpoint.